# Microservice integration with ELK stack as done in jhipster

Tags: jhipster

I want to try ELK stack independently instead of using  jhispter console.
I wanted to understand how spring boot microservice is integrated with ligstash.
As I see only jhipster.logstash enabled flag is set in application.yml file. I want to know what is the java file in jhipster framework which integrates application logs with logstash ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [LoggingConfiguration.java](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-microservice/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/jhipster/sample/config/LoggingConfiguration.java) and it uses [this logstash appender library](https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder).